# Qstring error. Saving from Textpool to string

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I've been trying to make simple 'typing game' where program is checking if input = showcased word.

I'm trying to use Qt GUI, so I've placed two text widgets, and "play" button.
However, there is a problem with string (or QString).

```
Error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'QString' and 'void')
 wprowadzone = ui->taker->textChanged();
             ^
```

How can I make this code work?
Thanks for any help.

mainwindow.cpp

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "score.h"
#include <qthread.h>



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionZako_cz_triggered()
{
    this->close();
}

void MainWindow::on_actionQt_info_triggered()
{
    QApplication::aboutQt();
}

void MainWindow::on_wyjdz_button_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}


void MainWindow::on_graj_button_clicked()
{
    slowo=s.slowa[rand()%s.slowa.size()];
    ui->giver->setText(slowo);
    wprowadzone = ui->taker->textChanged();
    QThread::sleep(5);
    game();
    //ui->SCORE->display(wyniki)
}

void MainWindow::on_SCORE_overflow()
{

}
```

game.cpp

```
#include "game.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "slowka.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMainWindow.h>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <string>
#include <QStringList>




using namespace std;



game::game()
{

    int proby = 0;
    int lives = 3;
    int wynik = 0;

    while (proby > lives)
    {

        if(wprowadzone != slowo)
        {
           wynik -= 1;
           proby += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            wynik += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

slowka.cpp (words database)

```
#include "slowka.h"

Slowka::Slowka()
{
    slowa<<"test";
    slowa<<"inny test";
    slowa<<"inniejszy";

}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

#include "slowka.h"



namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    QString slowo;
    QString wprowadzone;
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


private slots:
    void on_actionZako_cz_triggered();

    void on_actionQt_info_triggered();

    void on_wyjdz_button_clicked();

    void on_graj_button_clicked();




    void on_SCORE_overflow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Slowka s;

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "slowka.h"
#include <QMainWindow>



class game
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString slowo;
    QString wprowadzone;
public:
    game();
private:
    Slowka s;


};

#endif // GAME_H
```

slowka.h

```
#ifndef SLOWKA_H
#define SLOWKA_H
#include <QStringList>

class Slowka
{
public:
    Slowka();
    QStringList slowa;
};

#endif // SLOWKA_H
```

'graj' is the 'play' button
'proby' is the number of failed tries
'wynik' is the score

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#text-prop

> textChanged is a signal that you can send when the text changes

Use

> QString   text() const

instead

Another useful method:

> modified : bool

to check if the text was modified by the user

**Update** to answer additional comment questions:

It is best to declare all variables as `private`.

Add functions to "set" and "get" their value.

The only place you would need the `QString` mentioned, is in `mainwindow.h`. In `game.h`, use the `get` method to get its value, and the `set` to change the value.

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    void setSlowo(QString s) { slowo = s; }
    QString getSlovo() const { return slovo; }
    // same for wprowadzone

private slots:
    ......

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Slowka s;
    QString slowo;
    QString wprowadzone;

};
```

**Comment** I suggest to start with a design, if you write too much code without having a clear picture of what classes you have and how they connect, you will have much trouble later.

Comment: Do you know if 'wprowadzone' from mainwindow.cpp is the same as 'wprowadzone' from game.cpp? Or how can I achieve that?

Comment: they are not the same

Comment: How can I pass these Qstrings from mainwindow to game so I can use them there?

Comment: See how my example works for you - it is best as you will have more answers, to accept this answer since it solves the problem you asked. And then ask another question for the exact problem.

Comment: What do I have to add to game.h?

Comment: You would have to instantiate a window object. Then call that object.getSlowo(). This seems wrong though... Your window class should be including the game class, i think, not the other way around. Try to figure out how your classes interract first.